# Service Availability Checking

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

This is going to be a lengthy question.
First of all what I need to get done is to display available services(service will be either room1,room2,pool1,pool2 etc.) for a given period. 
I have three tables which could be related to this query. 
1. Service Type Table : Room,Pool etc.
2. Service Table: R1,R2,P1,P2 etc.
3. Items Reserved Table : This table holds a record for each service consumed by a given reservation ID.

Following is the snap of db diagram.

[image]

The system user will input Res_ID,Cust_ID,Date_In,Date_Out and select the service type from combo box. Then I have following View1 to  get available service Ids

```
(SELECT dbo.Items_Reserved.Service_ID
  FROM dbo.Items_Reserved INNER JOIN
  dbo.Reservation ON dbo.Items_Reserved.Res_ID = dbo.Reservation.Res_ID
  WHERE (dbo.Items_Reserved.Date_In > '$date_in') AND (dbo.Items_Reserved.Date_Out < '$date_out'))
```

First of all I want to know whether this is correct. I can not check whether this is correct as I dont know how to execute this view in my codes.

I use sql server and vb.net

Please help. I searched every where and could not find an answer.

Comment: Can you not try running the sql in the sql query tool in SQL Mgmt studio?

Comment: I did and it gives "null"

Comment: Would that not mean there are no services matching the reservation for that date range/

Comment: It seems so,since the query is correct can anybody please tell me how to use this in my application as I have to run another view on this selected data

Comment: Are you just asking how to execute this query, against your database, from within your VB.net application?